# Php Curl Login Trouble

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I'm really amateur to php curl. I would like to know how to login to a site with form like:

```
<form method="post" action="/log.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value="a49e4ebb5b71d0745573d37331bfc2cb2880" />Username: 
  <input type="text" name="user" />Password: 
  <input type="password" name="pass" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
```

Here you can see a fieldname called "sessionid". It just keeps on changing in every reload. So when i try to login with the curl, it says 'Invalid Session'. So can anyone please help me?

Comment: Show more of your code. "Here you can see..." You say - but there is no code, no session ID?...

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. Sorry for that. Please try to help me

Comment: show your existing php code

Comment: `$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.site.come';
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'sessionid='.$id.'&user=pxpclips&pass=thenewageoutlawsbtc&submit=Login');
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10);
// EXECUTE 1st REQUEST(FORM LOGIN)
$store = curl_exec ($ch);`
please note that i put `$id` empty. I just want to get that. I'm searching in google from almost 2 days for this. Any solutions?

Comment: Also keep in mind you can't use cURL to login into a site that uses a javascript\ajax login

Comment: It simply uses php. Any solution to get the sessionid?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is absolutely normal.

Your autologin process can be explained this way :

[image]

Your problem is at the step 4 : you cannot set a cookie for another domain.

- Your website www.autologin.com has the domain autologin.com
- The target website www.protected-site.com has the domain protected-site.com

If you try to set a cookie from www.autologin.com to the domain protected-site.com, your browser will ignore it.

Comment: There is no solution for security reasons, imagine what could be the web if every domain could set any cookies anywhere? If you're the only one that uses the auto-login system, you can trick your browser to make it believe your website is on the target domain using your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29), but that's quite geeky and not easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your cURL script should perform his own Login with user and password. There are several Methods (Basic, NTLM, ...) supported by cURL. Further, cURL can handle its own cookies using a cookie jar.

Answer (score 0):

But once i found a blog where it's admin made a facebook status updater script with curl and i missed it. Facebook is having session ids right? But how did he managed to do that?